# Keep the argument name when mapping a function type

Tags: typescript

Say I want to map a function's result:

```
(bob: Bob) => R
  =>
(bob: Bob) => R2
```

Is there any way to do so while keeping the argument name intact? (e.g `bob` instead of a generic name like `a`)

Comment: I'm quite confused by this question. Could you elaborate? Give us some larger example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about keeping the parameter names that code completion displays then there is no sintactic way to ensure those are preserved. The best way we can map arguments is using tuples with the [tuples in rest parameters feature in 3.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897). Since tuples are positional, they, in theory, have no name for each item in the tuple (only the position matters).

That being said, typescript does preserve the original name of the parameter if you map a function using the feature, it just does not display this information consistently. take this example:

```
class Bob { }
let fn : (bob: Bob) => string

type Arguments<T extends (...a:any[])=> any> = T extends (...a:infer A)=> any ? A: []
function trasform<T extends (...a: any[]) => any>(inFn: T): (...a: Arguments<T>) => number {
  return null as any;
}

let fnOut = trasform(fn);

fnOut(new Bob)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20class%20Bob%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20let%20fn%20%3A%20(bob%3A%20Bob)%20%3D%3E%20string%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20type%20Arguments%3CT%20extends%20(...a%3Aany%5B%5D)%3D%3E%20any%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20(...a%3Ainfer%20A)%3D%3E%20any%20%3F%20A%3A%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20function%20trasform%3CT%20extends%20(...a%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20any%3E(inFn%3A%20T)%3A%20(...a%3A%20Arguments%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20let%20fnOut%20%3D%20trasform(fn)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20fnOut(new%20Bob))

If you hover over `fnOut` you will see the original names:

[image]

If you open a `(` you will just see the tuple type:

[image]

There is also a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28127) relating to this behavior, I would suggest upvoting it if you want this improvement.

Comment: That was exactly my question, yes. I was using something like this :

type MappedReturn<F, R2> =
    F extends () => infer R ? () => R2 :
    etc

I used your tuple trick and it works exactly like you said it should. Cheers, and hopefully that bug get fixed.